# MySQL includes a specific row with order by

Tags: mysql, sql

Given 2 tables, I want to generate top 3 highest amount from [Purchase] table.
Additional criteria is [Crocs] must be included in top 3 of the records.

I have following SQL, but it cannot generates the result as I wanted (Result A), please guide me on how to pull out the result in Result B. Thank you.

Table (Purchase):

```
Purchase_ID | StoreID | Amount
------------|---------|--------
  1         |  21     |   22
  2         |  23     |   13
  3         |  25     |   6
  4         |  26     |   23
  5         |  28     |   18
```

Table (Store):

```
Store_ID | StoreName     
---------|----------
  21     |  Adidas
  22     |  Nike
  23     |  Puma
  24     |  New Balance
  25     |  Crocs
  26     |  Converse
```

SQL:

```
SELECT IF(SUM(amount) IS NULL, 0, SUM(amount)) as totalAmount
FROM (
    SELECT a.amount
    FROM purchase a
    INNER JOIN store b
    ON a.store_id = b.storeid
    GROUP BY a.amount
    HAVING b.StoreName = 'Crocs'
    ORDER BY a.amount DESC
    LIMIT 3
) t
```

Result A: $6

Explanation A: Amount of Crocs is $6

Result B: $51

Explanation B: Total Amount of top 3 = $22 (Adidas) + 23 (Puma) + $6 (Crocs)

Comment: Why result B is 51?

Comment: you have a category from b but you dont have field on it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from scaisEdge is almost right, but the first query could also return a row with crocs and the sorting is wrong (order by max(a.amount) limit 2 means that the lowest 2 results will be shown). Additionally you could wrap the query in another select query to sort the results

```
  SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT b.storename, max(a.amount) as maxAmount
      FROM purchase a
      INNER JOIN store b ON a.store_id = b.storeid
      WHERE b.storename != 'crocks'
      GROUP BY a.storename
      ORDER BY max(a.amount) DESC 
      LIMIT 2
    UNION 
      SELECT b.storename, a.amount as maxAmount
      FROM purchase a
      INNER JOIN store b
      ON a.store_id = b.storeid
      WHERE b.storename='crocks'
      ORDER BY a.amount DESC
      LIMIT 1
  ) ORDER BY maxAmount DESC
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You could use an union

```
  SELECT b.storename, max(a.amount)
  FROM purchase a
  INNER JOIN store b
  ON a.store_id = b.storeid
  GROUP BY a.storename
  order by max(a.amount) limit 2
  union 
  SELECT b.storename, a.amount
  FROM purchase a
  INNER JOIN store b
  ON a.store_id = b.storeid
  where b.storename='crocks'
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
SELECT sum(amount)as sum_amount,a.store_id,storename,category from
(select amount,store_id  from tbl_purchase) as a

inner JOIN

(select store_id,storename,category from tbl_store)as b on a.store_id = b.store_id where b.category = 'supermarket' GROUP BY category
```